# How to sort object list based on priority input

Tags: php, sql, symfony, columnsorting, pimcore

The problem: I need to sort a list of objects called tournament through 3 different criteria.

1. Field called start(timestamp)
2. Field called game__id
3. Field called platform__id

no. 3. is problematic, because the CMS(pimcore) content managers want this order: Ps4 -> Xbox -> Pc, however pimcore databases are autogenerated and you don't know the id of the platform, so you can't always rely on Ps4 being the first etc.

Part of the solution:

Create a field 'priority' in the object platform by which the content team can go into each one and select 1, 2, 3, 4 etc.

Sort these priority fields(uasort) and then show the tournaments based on the priority of the platforms(Ps4 -> Xbox -> Pc or even vice versa if one wants to).

Code:

```
$tournamentList = new Tournament\Listing();
$tournamentList->setCondition('start >= unix_timestamp(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY)');    // fetch only not finished
$tournamentList->setOrder('ASC');

$platformList->getObjects();
$platformObject = $platformList->objects;
uasort($platformObject, function ($a, $b) {
    if ($a->getPriority() == $b->getPriority()) {
        return 0;
    }

    return ($a->getPriority() > $b->getPriority()) ? +1 : -1;
});

foreach ($platformObject as $platform) {
    $priority = $platform->getPriority();
}

$tournamentList->setOrderKey([
    'start',
    'game__id',
]);
```

This is where I'm stuck, yes I filtered through the input and now I have 1, 2, 3, but how do I sort my tournaments based on the platforms and based on their priority field?!

Comment: What do you mean by "stuck"? What's missing, and what have you tried to get further?

Comment: @NicoHaase I tried firstly planning it, but it was starting to become too complex. If I want to compare the priority input values, what should I compare them too? Is there a specific sql clause for that or should I write an sql function? That's what I was thinking